# Issue with Inline Code Highlighting using tcbox and mintedinline - Renders # as ##

Tags: tcolorbox, minted

I've created a command for inline code highlighting using tcbox and mintedinline, but I'm encountering a problem. When I attempt to write just a #, it renders as ##. I've experimented with various options for tcbox, but nothing seems to resolve the issue. Interestingly, when I use only mintedinline, it works as expected. Therefore, I don't believe the problem lies in my \setminted configuration.

Any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Minimal latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{codeinlineBlue}{HTML}{CFE2FC}
\newcommand\mystrut{\rule[-2.5pt]{0pt}{12pt}}
\newcommand{\codeinline}[2][text]{%
    \tcbox[
      on line,
      boxsep=0pt,
      left=2pt,
      right=2pt,
      top=0pt,
      bottom=0pt,
      enlarge top initially by=-4pt,
      enlarge bottom by=-4pt,
      enlarge right by=-4pt,
      enlarge left by=-2pt,
      opacityframe=0,
      colback=codeinlineBlue,
      fontupper={\ttfamily\mystrut},
      fontlower={\ttfamily\mystrut}]
      {\mintinline{#1}{#2}}
}

\begin{document}

Text before code \codeinline{int main() \{ return 0; \}}, text after. Problem: \codeinline{#}.
This works as expected: \mintinline{text}{#}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, and i just now noticed that the `.` from the first sentence is in a newline. This looks weird and I don't know how to change this. im guessing it has something to do with the `\tcbox` directly before the `.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should gather the argument verbatim (but you'll not be able to use `\codeinline` as an argument to another command). In order to do this you use `\NewTotalTCBox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse}

\definecolor{codeinlineBlue}{HTML}{CFE2FC}
\newcommand\mystrut{\rule[-2.5pt]{0pt}{12pt}}

\NewTotalTCBox{\codeinline}{O{text}v}{
  on line,
  boxsep=0pt,
  left=2pt,
  right=2pt,
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  enlarge top initially by=-4pt,
  enlarge bottom by=-4pt,
  enlarge right by=-4pt,
  enlarge left by=-2pt,
  opacityframe=0,
  colback=codeinlineBlue,
  fontupper={\ttfamily\mystrut},
  %fontlower={\ttfamily\mystrut},
}{\mintinline{#1}{#2}}


\begin{document}

Text before code \codeinline{int main() \{ return 0; \}}, 
text after. Problem: \codeinline{#}.
This works as expected: \mintinline{text}{#}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! How can I escape inside that? Because I need to write a `~`and it always prints this hight one like in `ñ` but without the `n` (hope its understandable what I mean).

Comment: @OliverHihn Sorry, you should find a monospaced font that does what you like.

Comment: Thank you, I settled for cascadia-code. It looks even better imo.